# checking if there is valid data before implode

Tags: php, arrays, implode

i have a array built dynamically, but i need to check if it is empty before process it (implode it)

is there a way like isset or simply checking the array index...

I just need to know if it is not empty , but the array even when empty keeps given me count of 1

edited:

my array is build with this code

```
$( function() {
$( "#btn4" ).click( function() {

    var cid = new Array();
    $( "input[name='cid[]']:checked" ).each( function() {
            cid.push( $( this ).val() );
```

i then send it trow a ajax $_post
and if there is a checkbox selected every thing works fine, but if is empty i get a implode error ...
i tryed to check if is empty $array , i tryed to count $array , but nothing works...

Comment: [is_array](http://www.php.net) will check if it is an array. [count](http://www.php.net) will tell you how many elements are in the array. Perhaps that's all you really need?

Comment: `if (!empty(array_filter($array))) { implode($array); }`

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
if(count($arr))
```

`count()` checks the amount of items in the array, therefore `0` elements will evaluate to `false`;

Comment: `count` returns int, not bool.

Comment: i'm counting check boxes , and when there is no check box selected i still have a count of 1 with the count($array)

Comment: @user2798634 - It should return 0 if there are no elements in the array.... do you have empty elements in the array?

Comment: @OptimusCrime, `count()` returns `int` and it's truthy if not `0` so it's ok.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha - True, but I still think it is very ugly. Would not work in Java and other strick languages.

Comment: well then it's a good thing OP isn't asking how to do it in other languages

Comment: I would even use `if($arr)` to check empty or not, because it's `PHP`.

Comment: i checked it with       $nr = count($array); then the echo $nr give me 1 when it should be 0

Comment: @user2798634 Then there is one element in your array, var_dump($array) to see what it contains

Comment: returned NULL.. when i have 1 2 or 3 checkbox selected...doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: var_dump() will only return NULL if you don't have an array, but have an actual NULL... edit your question and show the __full__ output of the var_dump()

Comment: ok that was because i had a spelling error ...sorry . it now returns string(0) ""

Comment: this is what i get with multiple check boxes      array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "AMB0001" [1]=> string(7) "AMB0009" } guessing string (7)is the caracters count?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($arr) > 0) {
    // Do stuff
}
```